# Get Existing Outlook Addin Information from External C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I already have a C#-based Outlook Addin application which may or may not be installed on my clients versions of Outlook. Is it possible to determin whether the addin is installed and enabled from an external C# application, running on the same client's machine? And if so, how?

Many thanks in advance!
John

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing via MSI, you can check if it has been installed with the Windows Installer API (see [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974653) for more, [P/Invoke.net has a C# example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msi.msigetproductinfo)).

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me so quickly @Mitch. Unfortunately I am not installing via MSI. However, I did manage to pull together an answer that suited my needs in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the following code solved my problem:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

...

public static bool IsOutlookAddinEnabled(string addinName)
{
    bool isEnabled = false;

    Outlook.Application outlookApp = null;

    if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Length > 0)
    {
        outlookApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
    }
    else
    {
        outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        nameSpace = null;
    }

    try
    {
        COMAddIn addin = outlookApp.COMAddIns.Item(addinName);
        isEnabled = addin.Connect;
    }
    catch { }

    return isEnabled;
}
```

Many thanks to Mitch for his quick response.